# Creating custom field for rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, form-helpers

I'm trying to create a custom field for postgres's `numrange` datatype with the script [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-field). The generated engine (is it?) contains the form helper below, but I couldn't find the documentation for the `form.send` method anywhere. **Could anyone point me to it so that I can modify partial?**

```
= form.send field.view_helper, field.method_name, field._html_attributes
```

What I'm trying to do is create two input and parse it into a Range in the rails_admin field type class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I created some custom fields to deal with arrays.  Here is a useful article https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1218

```
class RailsAdminArray < RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Base
  register_instance_option :formatted_value do
    value.join(',') if value
  end
end
class RailsAdminStringArray < RailsAdminArray
  RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::register(:string_array, self)
  def parse_input(params)
    if params[name].is_a?(::String)
      params[name] = params[name].split(',').collect{|s| s.strip}
    end
  end
end
class RailsAdminIntArray < RailsAdminArray
  RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::register(:int_array, self)
  def parse_input(params)
    if params[name].is_a?(::String)
      params[name] = params[name].delete(' ').split(',').collect{|x| x.to_i}
    end
  end
end
```

Then I added this to my rails_admin.rb.

```
require Rails.root.join('lib', 'rails_admin', 'custom_fields.rb')
...
edit do
  field :tags, :string_array
end
```